# Soundplayer is stopping before the end of the wav file

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working with Visual C++ 2010 Express I’ve got Windows's [`PlaySound` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) playing `c:\music.wav`.

The sound stops before the end. If I replace `C:\music.wav` with a different `.wav` file (overwrite it) soundplayer stops at a different point, but at the same point depending on the `.wav` file that replaced `c:\music.wav`. i.e

1. copy 1.wav c:\music.wav click program stops 5 seconds in does not reach the end
2. copy 2.wav c:\music.wav click program stops 30 seconds in does not reach the end
3. Repeat step 1 sound stops again 5 seconds in.
4. Repeat setp 2 sound stops again 30 seconds in.

Can anyone help?

C++ code is:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("c:\\Music.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
```

Comment: What library are you using to play the sound?

Comment: @Caesar - Use of the SND_SYNC flag suggests that its the same PlaySound that is found in Winmm.dll (a standard component of windows) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user3032522: do you have the same problem if you play the .wav files in Windows MediaPlayer, or any other player app? If so, then the problem is in the .wav files themselves, such as maybe their RIFF header is malformed so it is truncating the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lightness Races in Orbit im using WinMM.lib

Comment: Also any file copyied over c:\music.wav plays right throgh in Windows Media Player, with out problems.

Comment: I Have re-written the code still got the same problem. Done a browser function, Double click on the .wav but what ever I select stops before the end. Now useing